# Проблема с выполнением скрипта

Tags: ajax, javascript, html, json

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема.
Есть POST скрипт.
Он написать правильно, кроме одного пункта. При нажатии на кнопку, перебрасывает на новую страницу, с JSON ответом.
Как исправить данную проблему?
Вот собственно сам скрипт:

```
 $('.form_test_form').on('submit', function () {
    var $form = $(this);
    var submitParams = $form.serialize();
    var url = $form.attr('action');
    var responseField = responseBody.find(".response-field");
    var requestURL = window.location.host + $form.attr('action');
    $this.find(".request-url-field").text(requestURL);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        processData: true,
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        data: submitParams,
        headers: ({"Auth-Secret": $("input[id='authpass']").val()}),
        success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
            var msg = "status: " + request.status + " (" + request.statusText + ")\n\n" + data;
            responseField.text(msg);
        },
        error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var msg = "status: " + request.status + " (" + request.statusText + ")";
            responseField.text(msg);
            if (request.status == 403 || request.status == 404){
                wgpass();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Insider, напоминаю - отмечайте ответы, которые действительно ответили на ваш вопрос, это поможет другим с подобной проблемой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()`
Иначе браузер выполнит свой переход, а нам же это не нужно?
Значит отменим.

Comment: А в какую строку это вставлять?

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение к ответу [@TheDoctor](/users/31688/thedoctor).

```
$('.form_test_form').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  ....
});
```

И да, все ваши объявления переменных поставьте под "знамёна" одного `var`:

```
var $form = $(this),
    submitParams = $form.serialize(),
    url = $form.attr('action'),
    responseField = responseBody.find(".response-field"),
    requestURL = window.location.host + $form.attr('action');
```

Так гораздо чище.

И непонятно, откуда у Вас берётся переменная `$this.`

```
$this.find(".request-url-field").text(requestURL);
```

Далее, вы правильно делаете, что кэшируете элемент формы `$form = $(this);`, но почему-то в этом месте

```
$("input[id='authpass']").val();
```

кэш не используете.

Может быть стоит:

```
$form.find('#authpass').val();
```

Comment: а зачем нам кэшировать пароль, если его можно изменить по потребности? )

Comment: Часть Кода - $this.find(".request-url-field").text(requestURL); воспроизводится с ошибкой.

Comment: @Insider, разумеется с ошибкой - переменной `$this` не существует.  
Вероятно просто неправильно написана переменная `$form`, которая определена выше.